# Interview questions for talent-sourcers/managers

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

There are several questions on this site about good questions to ask a recruiter, but as far as I can see, they mostly pertain to a *third-party* head-hunter.

I've recently faced several "talent managers" that work full-time for the company I'm interviewing for, and sometimes find myself a bit stuck for good questions in my prep work.

Most of the things I want to know (as a programmer) are technical, or specifics on how a certain team operates. The interview context is sufficiently different that a lot of the suggestions made in previous questions about recruiters in general don't seem appropriate for this scenario.

So what do you think are the important things to know?

Comment: Are you asking what to look for when applying for a software job? I can't imagine a large percentage of the recommendations only apply to talking to head hunters.

Comment: @JeffO I'm specifically asking for advice on what to ask in-house talent hunters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some questions I like to ask in-house recruiters:

> 1. What are the steps in the interview process for a candidate like myself? How long does each of portion take?

Asking about next steps means everyone is clear about what supposed to happen. Also gives you an idea when it is appropriate to start bugging your recruiter for an update.

> 2. Do you have any preparation materials you recommend for the technical interview?

Some recruiters will provide this material without asking such as Google and Square. Some might suggest you look at the company's technical blog. Others assume you can find your own.

> 3. Can you email me the job description?

Make sure you and your recruiter both understand what job opening(s) or teams in the company for which you are being considered. With "cold calls," I really like to see the job description and also get an email address for the recruiter in the process.

> 4. Thank you. You have been very thorough and already answered my questions. I don't have any other questions at this time. Could I contact you if some come up?

Sometimes the recruiter is very proactive and answers all my questions right off the bat. I just thank them for their time and ask if I could contact them again for questions.

Answer (score 1):

Being they are recruiters they might be privy to how well those canidates they do hire do. Ask them questions about what they find the best candidates for the company usually are, what they look for in a good canidate, and any special skills they find especially valuable.